# <super> + <down> <down> to minimize?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

<kbd>super</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd> will un-maximize. Is there a way that I could press down a second time and have it minimzie?

Comment: Probably you can try with `super+D`

Answer (score 0):

You can go to keyboard shortcuts/keybindings under "Settings"->"Devices"->"Keyboard"

Scroll down to the last section "Windows" and edit the "Hide Window" shortcut from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to something else

However your behavior with two taps of one key and a notion of what state the window is in will require advanced scripting.

maybe you can just set minimise window to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> and set "window restore" to something that seems more native to you but keep in mind minimising a window deselects it and selects whatever window behind it was topmost instead. (so you'll break the chain in move commands you were giving to that window if that's your thing, which I can relate to)

All in all I'm not sure you really really want this. Hope this helped :)